# What is the max limit for max_result_window setting for an index in Elasticsearch? How to set it to unlimited?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch a lot of records using Elasticsearch. Earlier, the max limit was capped at 10000 I guess. Then I increased it to 999999999 by doing this ->

```
{
"index": {
    "blocks": {
        "read_only_allow_delete": "false"
                },
     "max_result_window" : "999999999"
        }
}
```

and I got the response ->

```
 {
    "acknowledged": true
}
```

Now, I want to further increase it but I am getting below error when trying to do so.

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Failed to parse value [9000000000] for setting [index.max_result_window]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse value [9000000000] for setting [index.max_result_window]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "number_format_exception",
            "reason": "For input string: \"9000000000\""
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

How can I further increase it ? Is there any max value allowed for this setting? Is there any way to set it to unlimited?

Scroll API is out of scope since I couldnt use it in JReport.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655913/elk-how-do-i-retrieve-more-than-10000-results-events-in-elastic-search/41657964#41657964 (hint: use scroll instead)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I cant use Scroll API as I am using Elasticsearch in combination with Jreport and I couldnt find any way to scroll API in Jreport.