# Deep paging in ES

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, elastic-stack

I have an ES index. The document is from a mongo store

```
  {
    "id": "52abcsddfdf",
    "modifiedTime": 1585745999999,
    "createdTime" : 1585745999999,
    ....
  }
```

I have to scan the ES index based on modified time. I want to do this in batch of lets say 300.
My ES query will look like this.

```
GET cacargroup_gl_accounts/_search
{
  "from": 1, 
  "size": 300,
  "sort": [
    {
      "modifiedTime": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I do this, I think I will end up having a deep page problem as the document store is too big. I change my query to make it greater than modified time of last element in batch, but with this approach I can miss some documents whose modified time is same.

```
GET cacargroup_gl_accounts/_search
{
  "from": 1, 
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "modifiedTime": {
              "gt": 1566061889748
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "sort": [
    {
      "modifiedTime": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: To include docs with the same modified time or greater, you can use "gte" (greater than or equal)

Comment: Queries don't have issues with a size of 300, but from/size is also a good option

Comment: If you consider performing pagination for over 10,000 elements, you can use Scroll as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41657964/7674214