# ElasticSearch paginate over 10K result

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch's search feature only support 10K result by default. I know I can specific the "size" parameter in the search query, but this only applies to number of result to get back in one call.

If I want to iterate over 20K results using size=100, making 200 calls total. How should I do it?

Comment: You can use "size" and "from" parameter in your search query to run the same query. First iteration size: 100, from: 0. Second iteration size: 100, from: 100. Third iteration size: 100, from: 200. Would this work?

Comment: @BarkhaJain You can only do from "10000" is the max, but you do "10001" you will get error.

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64717295/4604579