# How to use opensearchpy to return ALL results from a query

Tags: python, opensearch

We dump all of our fastly logs into opensearch and I've been tasked with analyzing some of the logs on a large scale for SEO purposes. I need to look at ALL records that match my query. The number of records that match are GREATER than 10,000 which means I cannot use a simple search because even if I change the size I get an error saying my size cannot exceed 10,000 results.

Can anyone provide me with an example using opensearchpy that will return ALL results that fit my query? I have looked at the opensearchpy docs and I am not having any luck figuring that out.

```
client = OpenSearch(
    hosts=[{"host": host, "port": 443}],
    http_auth=auth,
    use_ssl=True,
    timeout=300,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
    pool_maxsize=20,
)

query = {
    "size": "10000",
    "timeout": "300s",
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"type": "req"}},
                {"range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "now-7d/d", "lte": "now/d"}}},
                {"wildcard": {"req_h_user_agent": {"value": "*googlebot*"}}},
            ]
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "@timestamp",
        "resp_status",
        "resp_bytes",
        "req_h_referer",
        "req_h_user_agent",
        "req_h_host",
        "req_uri",
        "total_response_time",
    ],
#     "_source": False,
}

response = client.scroll(
    body=query,
    index="fastly-*",
)
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655913/how-do-i-retrieve-more-than-10000-results-events-in-elasticsearch help? IIUC the difference between opensearch and elasticsearch should be unimportant in this case.

Comment: @kojiro it kind of does... however it looks like that answer provides solutions that would require me to delve a layer deeper and use the requests module to make http requests to the endpoint and figure out authentication. I was really hoping that someone somewhere would have figured out how to use what appears to be the standard opensearch python library to use the scroll feature, which is also present in the elasticsearch python library. Perhaps I'm being too lazy and should just use the requests module and figure out how to authenticate without the assistance of the opensearch library.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The docs are garbage, but this is what you need to do. I believe this is probably a common pattern and I'm just unfamiliar with it. There's probably a better way to loop through the pages as well (like maybe I won't receive a _scroll_id if there are no results left) but this way is working for me. Maybe someone can improve my answer.

edit: here's where I found how to do it. It's not in the official docs, but it is in the github repo here https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-py/blob/main/guides/search.md

```
client = OpenSearch(
    hosts=[{"host": host, "port": 443}],
    http_auth=auth,
    use_ssl=True,
    timeout=300,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
    pool_maxsize=20,
)

query = {
    "size": "10000",
    "timeout": "300s",
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"type": "req"}},
                {"range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "now-7d/d", "lte": "now/d"}}},
                {"wildcard": {"req_h_user_agent": {"value": "*googlebot*"}}},
            ]
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "@timestamp",
        "resp_status",
        "resp_bytes",
        "req_h_referer",
        "req_h_user_agent",
        "req_h_host",
        "req_uri",
        "total_response_time",
    ],
    "_source": False,
}

response = client.search(
    scroll='1m',
    body=query,
    index="fastly-*",
)

pagination_id = response["_scroll_id"]

with open("report.csv", "w") as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(
    [
        "timestamp",
        "content_type"
        "url",
        "response code",
        "bytes",
        "response_time",
        "referer",
        "user agent",
    ]
)

writer.writerow(
    [
        fields["@timestamp"][0],
        fields["content_type"][0],
        fields["req_h_host"][0] + fields["req_uri"][0],
        fields["resp_status"][0],
        fields["resp_bytes"][0],
        fields["total_response_time"],
        fields["req_h_referer"][0],
        fields["req_h_user_agent"][0],
    ]
)

while len(hits) != 0:
    response = client.scroll(
        scroll='1m',
        scroll_id=pagination_id
    )

    hits = response["hits"]["hits"]
        fields = hit["fields"]
        with open("report.csv", "a") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(
                [
                    fields["@timestamp"][0],
                    fields['content_type'][0],
                    fields["req_h_host"][0] + fields["req_uri"][0],
                    fields["resp_status"][0],
                    fields["resp_bytes"][0],
                    fields['total_response_time'][0],
                    fields["req_h_referer"][0],
                    fields["req_h_user_agent"][0],
                ]
            )
    pagination_id=response['_scroll_id']
```